# How to show missing edges with Freestyle edge mode?

Tags: edges, freestyle

Are there any settings to make edge marks appear at all angles when rendered? I edge marked part of Suzanne's head but when certain angles are rendered parts of the edge marks are invisible.

For example:
[image: edge marks working]

Edge Marks working ok at certain angles

[image: edge marks working]

Edge Marks are invisible at certain angles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**.

The edge disappears because it is no longer visible. This is more obvious on a shaded model:

[image]

If you want freestyle edges to be visible at all times, disable selection by visibility:

[image]